# How can i copy rows while creating?

Tags: mysql, copy, row

Greetings to everyone,

I am checking the questions about copying rows but i couldn't find a solution or i am searching wrong.

I am trying to upload multiple files and store some informations in 2 tables which rows are created at the same time while upload process.

I have 2 tables called "media" and "pmedia" structures are;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `media` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `media_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `ordering` int(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `i_product_id` (`product_id`,`media_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=267 ;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pmedia` (;
  `media_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `file_title` char(126) NOT NULL default '',
  `file_mimetype` char(64) NOT NULL default '',  
  PRIMARY KEY  (`media_id`),
  KEY `i_vendor_id` (`vendor_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=274 ;
```

I am uploading multiple images to "pmedia" which there is no problem with;

```
$query="INSERT into pmedia (`file_title`,`file_mimetype`) VALUES ('$file_name','$file_type') ; ";
```

But at the same time i want those uploaded files' Auto Increated column "media_id" also copied to "media" table..

Result should be after upload;

[image]

**EDIT2 :**
Ok guys that was the loop itself. I just made a write mistake. The below code works by the help and inspiration of Ruly and gaRex. Thank you so so much.

**EDIT :**

Here is the structure, and sorry for missing explanation. (I am not trying to do that in single query.)
How should i implement the loop? In this way it only writes the uploaded data only to pmedia.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }       


        $query="INSERT into pmedia (`file_title`,`file_mimetype`) VALUES ('$file_name','$file_type') ; ";
        $media_id = mysql_insert_id();

        $query2="INSERT into media (`media_id`) VALUES ($media_id) ; ";


    $desired_dir="user_data";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysql_query($query);
     mysql_query($query2);  

    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";


} }
?>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 way to do that:

1. Run multiple query

   After execute:

   ```
   $query="INSERT into pmedia (`file_title`,`file_mimetype`) VALUES ('$file_name','$file_type') ; ";
   ```

   Get the id for new record, use mysqli_insert_id

   http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

   Then execute:

   ```
   $query="INSERT into media (`id`,`product_id`, `media_id`, `ordering`) VALUES ($id, $product_id, $media_id, $ordering) ; ";
   ```
2. Use trigger, but for this case I'm sure since I think think you can get the value of id, product_id, ordering from pmedia table

**EDIT:**

To add several rows, you should have a loop, and in the loop you should do those three steps. The code should be like this:

```
// Looping {
    $query="INSERT into pmedia (`file_title`,`file_mimetype`) VALUES ('$file_name','$file_type') ; ";

    $media_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    $query="INSERT into media (`id`,`product_id`, `media_id`, `ordering`) VALUES ($id, $product_id, $media_id, $ordering) ; ";
// } Looping
```

Comment: Greetings Ruly;
Thanks for your help, but as far as i can understand mysqli_insert_id gets only the last record. I'm trying to make multiple uploads. I tried triggering before, i tried every way but no luck with that.

Comment: Correct, it only get the last new id, so if you want to insert several images, then you should loop the query right? And every time you run the query, get the last id, and run the second query. Look at the edited code above

Comment: Thanks for the way Ruly. But i couldn't make it work. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to insert multiple rows into pmedia in one query?

Most simple and reliable way will be to insert there by one row and only then update media table.

But if you want, you can try these two ways. They both dirty:

1. Add to pmedia some column with unique value, that can be set outside. Let it be our lovely GUID (see google) CHAR(36). Then in script generate this value and set to each row of pmedia. After you will not need any mysql`s insert ids as you will already have them generated by you. Then you can insert into media table by referring to pmedia in your insert query.

   insert into t1 (v1, v2) values ($v1, (select id from t2 where guid = $guid)), ...
2. Start transaction. Insert into pmedia, get last_insert_id() for last record. Then you can calculate id for first record as you now count of records.

But pls remember -- both ways are dirty and bad.

Comment: Hi gaRex, the reason i want to insert multiple rows is because i am trying to upload multiple images at the same time. "pmedia" is to collect all images for products and categories and "media" is just for products.
2nd way won't work because last_insert_id() gets only 1 row (as far as i know, i am not very good at mysql and php)
For the 1st way; i guess we should delete the GUID after copying rows to media i guess. Or maybe give another GUID for another product while copying.

Comment: Im' still not understand why do you want insert multiple rows in SINGLE query. Why dont' you want to do it in multiple queries?

Comment: After your 2nd "why", i started to think that i'm in a wrong way. :) Please forgive me but let me ask in this way and please lighten me. What is the easiest way to upload multiple images at the same time to a product? And for your previous post i am still trying to figure out how.

Comment: I was posting this questions at around 4am and i misunderstood what you wrote. I didn't want to do the process in "Single" query. I just showed in what position i am in. And i was asking what should be the next step. Sorry for my fault.